# How to use AVG( ) inside WHERE condition in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, average, where-clause

I was trying to update `Employee_Age` from 'Employee' table by increasing 10 years whose ages are not equal to average age.

I did try like this:

```
UPDATE Employee
SET Employee_Age = Employee_Age + 10
WHERE Employee_Age != (SELECT AVG(Employee_Age) FROM Employee)
```

But I get an error:

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'Employee' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem, is that with every update, you would get different results.

so use a temporary table like

```
UPDATE Employee
SET Employee_Age = Employee_Age + 10
WHERE Employee_Age != (SELECT AVG(Employee_Age) FROM (SELECT * FROM Employee) t1)
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it is working properly.